# How @RequestMapping internally works in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, request-mapping

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class Employee {
  @RequestMapping("/save")
  public void saveEmployee() {
    // saving employee
  }
}
```

How does `@RequestMapping` will work internally to map the request to the `saveEmployee` method?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

During application startup, Spring will identify all `Bean`s by way of XML Config, Java Config, or Component Scanning and store them in the `ApplicationContext`.

Spring Boot autoconfigures many Beans for you, including [RequestMappingHandlerMapping](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/fe1eb8b5f3ce4975bcbbb2a83192e84b32776175/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L402).

When this Bean is [initialized](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5f074343607bd156646c30b5226152d60ec506dd/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java#L193-L219) it scans the ApplicationContext for any Beans annotated with `@Controller`.

Then it iterates over each `Controller` bean and [looks](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5f074343607bd156646c30b5226152d60ec506dd/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java#L204-L209) for methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`.  Finally it persists these mapping/handler pairs in the [MappingRegistry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5f074343607bd156646c30b5226152d60ec506dd/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java#L475-L670)

The `DispatcherServlet` is the central HTTP request handler for your application and it will [search](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5f074343607bd156646c30b5226152d60ec506dd/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L570-L601) the `ApplicationContext` for any Beans that implement the `HandlerMapping` interface, which the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` Bean does (by way of inheritance).

Then it iterates over these beans asking them to resolve the corresponding handler for this request.  The `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean will resolve the handler by [searching](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5f074343607bd156646c30b5226152d60ec506dd/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java#L503-L505) its `MappingRegistry`.

When a match is found, the handler method is eventually [invoked](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5f074343607bd156646c30b5226152d60ec506dd/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L967).